# Sorting Glob results in reverse order and limiting to 2

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a list of files inside a folder but in reverse order and limiting to 2 (the last 2), there are a lot of good examples so I liked this one... but I'm trying to limit the amount of results, I almost have it but it gives me an error... can you guys help me?

```
<?php
foreach (glob("../../imagenes/medianas/*") as $files) {
$images[filectime($files)] = $files;
}
krsort($images);
foreach($images as $timestamp => $files) if ($limite++ < 2){

print "<img src='../../imagenes/medianas/". basename($files) ."' title=''>"."<br>";
}
?>
```

Thanks' a bunch for your help.

---

Sorry all, OK... I Fixed it, this is how it works... Thanks Jon, nice hint.
Here is the code for anyone who has the same issue

```
<?php
$limite = 0;
foreach (glob("../../imagenes/medianas/*") as $files) {
    $images[filectime($files)] = $files;
}
krsort($images);
foreach($images as $timestamp => $files) if ($limite++ < 2){

   print "<img src='../../imagenes/medianas/". basename($files) ."' title=''>"."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is $limite? Also what is the error?

Comment: $limite is the amount of results i want. And the error is:
Notice: Undefined variable: limite in E:\xampp\htdocs\asi\modulos\miniaturas\miniaturas2.php on line 7

Comment: First, it's not an error, it's a notice telling you that $limite is undefined. You have to define a initial value to $limite.

Comment: I understand, but I don't know how to. I've been trying for hours and nothing worked until I did this, It gives me the two last images, so it works but it gives the message and of course like I said at first, don't know what to do.

Comment: If you solved the problem, add the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over the `glob()` array, just add a `$count` and check it first:

```
$limite = 2;
$count = 0;
foreach(krsort(glob('...')) as $file)
  if($count++ <= $limite)
    // do what you do with $file
```

Comment: I'm so sorry... I don't understand... but I really want to